# how to use class object being created in stack

Tags: c#

I am new to c# . So cant figure out the below mentioned concept .

```
using System;
namespace vivek
{
    class viku
    {
        public void func1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base");
        }
    }
    class Behera
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            viku v;
            v.func1();
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling its showing the below error

```
 error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'v'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way for you to instruct the compiler to create an object on the stack in C# - you're working in a managed memory environment now, where the managed side of things has rules that decide where objects are created.

What ends up on the stack is purely an implementation detail. Usually, it will be your reference variables and any local [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)<sup>1</sup>, *provided* that these variables and value types are not being hoisted due to [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx), and that you're not writing code in an [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx) or [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx) method<sup>2</sup>.

To create any [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) object (`class` declares a reference type, `struct` or `enum` declares a value type), you have to use `new`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The fact that local value types *sometimes* end up on the stack is, as I say, an implementation detail. But there's a persistent myth that "value types go on the stack, reference types go in the heap". You shouldn't change your `class` to a `struct` just to force it to go on the stack (which it won't always be anyway).

<sup>2</sup>In all of these situations, the compiler actually re-writes the code that you've written, and what look like local variables become, in fact, fields of a new `class` that the compiler constructs for holding them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instanstiate object of class.

*Change*

```
viku v;
```

*To*

```
viku v = new viku();
```

Comment: so what does viku v ; means .. Is it not an object like we create stack object in C++

Comment: In effect all C# variables (except for value types like int, double, etc) are references, not objects.  You have to create instances to refer to.  There are no automatic stack-based objects here.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a C++ guy, one thing to help you visualize (but it's not exactly true, its just an analogy) is think of classes in C# as always being pointer refrences in C++.

So if we re-wrote your original code to the "equivilant" in C++ (ignore the memory leak, like I said it is just a basic analogy, not a exact truth) it would be:

```
namespace vivek
{
    class viku
    {
        public:
        void func1()
        {
            Console::WriteLine("Base");
        }
    }

    class Behera
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            viku* v;
            v->func1();
        }
    }
}
```

Now (if I assumed correctly that you know C++) it is obvious why your call to `v` did not work, it does not point at any instance of the `viku` class.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. The above program (with minor modifications to replace `Console::WriteLine` with `cout`, etc) compiles in gcc and works! My guess is that it is because C++ does not 1) have a compiler rule about variables being assigned before they are used and 2) do a "null" check before invoking instance methods. `func1` never accesses any of the memory the instance occupies so there is never the possibility of a segfault.

Comment: @mikez What "other Minor modifications" do you make? `v` should be a null pointer and you should get a null dereference error when you attempt to do `v->func1()`

Comment: Add a semicolon after the class definition, change `Main` to a top level function with the signature `int main()`. [Here](http://ideone.com/6rcv4W) is the result.

Comment: @mikez Color me confused, I even tried to [force a null reference execption](http://ideone.com/ublsxu) and it still worked. I guess I am more rusty than I thought in my C++.

Answer (score 1):

To create an object, you need to call a contructor

```
viku v = new viku();
```

or even shorter

```
var v = new viku();
```

You should read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx) about constructors

Comment: In c++ we can create the object and call the function as mentioned above . Is it something different in c# ? my question is whether in c# we can create object only by using new ?

Comment: When you use `new`, constructor of the object is called. It initializes object state and allocates the memory. Also in C# you cannot use unassigned variables

Answer (score 0):

I dont have idea about c# syntax but.. i think it might be

> viku v=new viku();
>   v.func1();